# Cannot deploy on Contracts-UI using local node

Tags: substrate-node-template, smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node

I'm following [this tutorial](https://use.ink/getting-started/deploy-your-contract). My local node seems to run fine but I can't deploy. The "Next" button is greyed out and there is no message that says what's wrong. What am I missing?

**Contracts-UI**
[image: Contracts-UI]

**Local node**
[image: node logs]
[image: node logs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using the substrate node template repo. Try to use the [substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node) instead.

### Install and run the node

- Clone the repo: `git clone https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git`
- Checkout version v0.17: `git checkout v0.17.0`
- There seem to be an issue with the --git flag in Cargo so I would recommend to clone the repo and use the `cargo install --path ./node/ --locked` command instead.
- run the node with the following command: `substrate-contracts-node --dev`